# Multi-BAM visualization with Tablet alignment viewer

Tags: alignment, viewer, samtools

I have been using the Tablet alignment viewer (http://bioinf.scri.ac.uk/tablet/) to visualize my bam alignment files. Because I want to compare different individuals, I need to open 2 or 3 BAM together on the same window. But Tablet doesn't seem to offer a multi-BAM viewing option or I wasn't able to find it yet!

Does anybody tknow whether this option is available in Tablet? If not, at least for comparing bam files, then Tablet isn't that useful to me. The thing is that I have found some other visualization tools, like MagicViewer, but Tablet interface is way much better.

Of course if anyone knows a viewer with a multi-viewing option and a nice interface, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TABLET doesn't support more than one BAM File at a time (For time being at least). So can go with other visualizers such as [IGV](http://www.broadinstitute.org/igv/), [SAVANT](http://genomesavant.com/) which supports more than one BAM visualization